# UITextField control events: UIControlEventEditingChanged vs. UIControlEventAllEditingEvents

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the difference between these two `UIControlEvents`?

The documentation says:

```
UIControlEventAllEditingEvents   // All editing touches for UITextField objects.
UIControlEventEditingChanged     // A touch making an editing change in a UITextField object.
```

Especially `UIControlEventAllEditingEvents` is not clear to me, as I don't get what *'all editing touches'* mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the event `UIControlEventAllEditingEvents` occurs whenever one of these occur:

```
UIControlEventEditingDidBegin 
UIControlEventEditingChanged
UIControlEventEditingDidEnd 
UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit
```

Comment: Hmm, it makes sense I think.